# How do I make Google script ignore empty cells when checking checkboxes in my google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I have this code

```
function checkBoxes(check) {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Requirment check")
 ws.getRange(2,3,43,10).setValue(check)
}
function ChckAllBoxes(){
  checkBoxes(true)
}
function UnchckAllBoxes(){
  checkBoxes(false)
}
```

**Does anyone know how i can make this code ignore empty cells ?**

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to ignore emty cells

Answer (score 0):

[`Range.check()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#check)  ignores empty cells:

> Ignores the cells in the range which currently do not contain either the checked or unchecked value configured.

```
ws.getRange(2,3,43,10)[check ? 'check' : 'uncheck']();
```